# Text temporarily drops down during jQuery .toggle() animation

Tags: jquery, animation

I have some HTML, CSS and jQuery that contracts some text when a button is clicked. It hides certain letters to reveal an abbreviation, by hiding all letters except the initials of each word.

It hides the letters in the `<span>` tags: `S<span>tack</span> E<span>xchange</span>`

The problem is that the remaining letters that aren't being animated to `display: none` (<kbd>S</kbd> and <kbd>E</kbd>) drop down temporarily as they move.

```js
$("button").on("click", function() {
  $("span").toggle('slow');
})
```

```css
p {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>Click</button>

<p>
  S<span>tack</span> E<span>xchange</span>
</p>
```

How do I prevent the initials from dropping down when the words contract?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a CSS `line-height` issue. The text is dropping down to fill extra `line-height` that is not being taken up.

Manually set `line-height` to an appropriate smaller value, and move the text down with a `margin`, since making `line-height` smaller moves the text up.

The animation now works smoothly.

```js
$("button").on("click", function() {
  $("span").toggle('slow');
})
```

```css
p {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: 50px;
  line-height: 10px;
}

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>Click</button>

<p>
  S<span>tack</span> E<span>xchange</span>
</p>
```